# How to merge list and a variable using lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to make a lambda function that basically works like an .append() function, I can't figure out how to do it.

```
y = lambda l,x: [l,x]
y([3,4,5],2)
```

This code returns "[[3, 4, 5], 2]", but i want it to return "[3, 4, 5, 2]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `lambda` really isn't supposed to be used as a named function just make an actual function or use the append function. But if this is necessary:

```
y = lambda l,x: [*l,x]
```

Although a def would be more appropriate and can also be done in one line:

```
def y(l,x): return [*l,x]
```

Comment: Thank you, normally i would use append or normal function but its a part of a task given by my teacher

Answer (score 1):

i guess that`ll be

```
lambda l,x:l+[x]
```